# Signal sampling question here please?

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, sampling

We have the signal \$y(t)=7\cos(wt) \$.We have \$f(s)=100~Hz\$.I need to find \$f(T)\$ and reconstruct the signal so that we wont have loss of signal.

I think that we need to take \$f(T)>2f(s)\$ so I take \$f(T)\$ for example 400.

$$
T = \frac {1}{ft} = \frac{1}{400} \\
w=2\pi*fs=200\pi \\
t=KT=\frac{k}{400} \\
y(k) =y(t)*ST(t) = y(kT)* S(t-k) \\
y(0)=7\cos(200\pi)*0* 0.0025*S(t-200kT)=0 \\
y(1)=7\cos(200\pi)*1*0.0025* S(t-200kT)=0
$$

am I doing this the right way?

Question: Can also find the solution of this exercise using MATLAB?

Comment: kindly use `Latex` while using math in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get what is \$S\$ in the question. But the answer you got is wrong.

The simplest way is to replace \$t\$ in \$y(t)\$ with \$\dfrac{k}{400}\$

$$y(k) = 7 \cos(200\pi\times \dfrac{k}{400})$$
where, \$k = 0,1,2,3....\$

$$y(0) = 7 \cos(200\pi\times \dfrac{0}{400}) = 1$$
$$y(1) = 7 \cos(200\pi\times \dfrac{1}{400}) = 0$$
$$y(2) = 7 \cos(200\pi\times \dfrac{2}{400}) = 1$$
$$\vdots$$

Yes. Matlab can do this easily. Try this.

```
k = 0:1:10;
y = 7*cos(200*pi*k/400);
```

Comment: Thank you.What does k = 0:1:10 mean in matlab?

Comment: it means k = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

Comment: Is the other part of the exercise alright? f(t)>2f(s) and so on?